# How to exclude columns with apply

Tags: r, list, multiple-columns, lapply

I want to exclude/copy rows/columns of multiple dataframes within a list in a list.
The code doesn't work yet. Maybe somebody here knows what to do.

```
Zelllysate_extr <- list()

#defining the list

Zelllysate_extr$X0809P3_extr <- X0809P3_extr

#defining the list within the list

X0809P3_extr = lapply(Zelllysate_colr[["X0809P3"]], function(x) {
  as.data.frame(x) <- Zelllysate_colr[["X0809P3_colr"]][2:1500, 1 & 3:4]
  return(x)
}) 

#defining the list for the dataframes to place in; 2:1500, 1 & 3:4 are the rows and columns to copy
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to iterate over the list, iterate over the *length* of the list.

```
X0809P3_extr = lapply(1: length(Zelllysate_colr[["X0809P3"]]), function(x) {
  Zelllysate_colr[["X0809P3_colr"]][[x]][2:1500, c(1, 3:4)]
})
```

You don't need a `return` or to set the value equal to something in `lapply`.

> I'm assuming that `Zelllysate_colr[["X0809P3"]]` is a list within the list `Zelllysate_colr`.

Most of the time the output from `dput(head(dataObject))` is enough, but I think you're working with lists of lists, so that might not be enough to see the structure.